# android: checking and changing image of button

Tags: android, image, android-layout

in my application i'm checking image of button for 1sec.n changing it.what happen is when first time it checks n changes image of button.and the 2nd time its not changing the image.
here is the code-

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {      
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Random rand=new Random();
                    int num = rand.nextInt(buttonIds.length);
                    int buttonId = buttonIds[num];
                    Button bb=(Button) findViewById(buttonId);

                    Drawable a=bb.getBackground();

                    if(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy).equals(a))
                    {
                    bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
                    }
                    else
                     {
                    bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whoa);
                     }

                }
            });
        }

    },0, 1000);
```

first time image of button is happy(name of image file).
how can i change image of button and also check?? 
Thanku

Comment: Why does the int `num` given a value two times in a row? The line `int num=rand.nextInt(9)+1;` isn't neccesary.

Comment: yeah.no use of first num

Comment: You could always use a `ImageButton` instead of just a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your if condition is not correct, you a checking if the background image is happy, you are again setting happy..instead you should set whoa...

Comment: i did that also.when i'm setting it whoa nothing is done.but when its happy image is changing

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a boolean(isHappy) to notify if the picture is happy or not, it is easier and faster since you don't have to instance the current image and maybe it will solve your problem, I am not completely sure about "equals" works like that, but is only my guess.

Anyway I think your code has a small mistake, the condition makes the picture to be always happy.